# Docusign SDK error in placing "sign_here" tabs in particular document

Tags: python-3.x, docusignapi

I am using python SDK version 3.3 and I am trying to place tabs using anchor string. My use case is sending multiple documents through a single envelope to multiple recipients.

For recipient 1, the anchor string in document 1 is (let us say) *“Sign here”* and anchor string in document 2 is *“Assessee”*.

For recipient 2, the anchor string in document 2 is *“Sign here”*.

Now when I am anchoring tabs, I am passing the recipient id , document id and the anchor string, I even tried by parsing the page number. Docusign seems to be searching for anchor string across all the documents.
*For example:* I get a error message saying “Assessee” is not found, but I specifically mentioned "Assessee" for document 2. What am I missing here? Please help

*----- Snippet -----*

```
sign_here1 = docusign.SignHere(anchor_string='Sign here',
                               recipient_id='1',
                               document_id= '1',
                               anchor_units='inches',
                               anchor_y_offset='0.6', 
                               anchor_x_offset='0.5',
                               anchor_ignore_if_not_present=False
                              )
sign_here2 = docusign.SignHere(anchor_string='Assessee',
                               recipient_id='1',
                               document_id= '2',
                               anchor_units='inches',
                               anchor_y_offset='0.6', 
                               anchor_x_offset='0.5',
                               anchor_ignore_if_not_present=False
                              )
sign_here3 = docusign.SignHere(anchor_string='Sign here: ',
                               recipient_id='2',
                               document_id= '2',
                               anchor_units='inches',
                               anchor_y_offset='0.6', 
                               anchor_x_offset='0.5',
                               anchor_ignore_if_not_present=False
                              )
```

*----- Error message -----*
*"errorCode":"ANCHOR_TAB_STRING_NOT_FOUND","message":"The specified Anchor Tab string was not found in the document. Anchor Tab String \"Assessee\" not found."*[image]*This is the output, I recieve. But I have mentioned only document_id '2' in sign_here2*

Answer (score 0):

Your code has :

```
anchor_string='Assessee'
```

This means DocuSign scans the document and looks for this word. If the word cannot be found - this tab cannot be placed.
The idea of an anchor string is to find how to place the tab based on some text, a few characters, a word or something in the document.

Since, you also have x_position and y_position, maybe you misunderstood how tab positioning work? you typically have one or the other.
there's an offset you can use for the anchor, but that's different that x_position.
Try to just remove the anchor_string and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited the code snippet, previously I posted the wrong one. The problem I am facing here is even though I have mentioned to place my "sign_here" tab in document_id 2 for anchor string "Assessee".                                              
 It is getting placed in both the documents.